# Redirecting HTTP requests to HTTPS not always working

Tags: node.js, https, http-redirect

I have an application written using Node. Any requests coming over HTTP is redirected to HTTPS. In some cases the redirection happens successfully (browser receives a HTTP 302) however most of the cases the redirection does not occur(browser receives just a HTTP 200).

What should i do to ensure the redirection always occurs ?

Logic i currently use

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
   console.log("Entering secure redirect route");
   if(!req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']) {
      console.log("Attempting to access using http protocol");
   } else {
      console.log("Attempting to access using https protocol");
   }
   console.log("Attempting to access host " + req.host);
   console.log("Attempting to access url " + req.originalUrl);
   if(!req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']) {
     console.log("Redirecting to " + "https://" + req.host + req.url);
     res.redirect("https://" + req.host + req.url);        
         res.end(); 
    } else {
         next();
      }
   } else {
    next();
   }
};
```

Comment: What are you doing now?

Comment: i'm checking if 'x-forwarded-proto' is not defined and then redirecting the resource over https else allowing the appropriate route handler to serve the request and serve the static resource

Comment: Can you post that code?

Comment: I've added the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not enough that the x-forwarded-proto header is set if the value is not HTTPS. Whoever is forwarding the traffic must be accepting HTTP connections.

console.log out the value of x-forwarded-proto every time, and I suspect sometimes the value is HTTP

Comment: hmm, you are certain it is never set when an http request is recieved?

I got what I was thinking from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/TerminologyandKeyConcepts.html#x-forwarded-headers

Comment: Thanks Catalyst. You nailed the issue :-)

Comment: No problem, I remember this got me for a whole afternoon once :)

Comment: I lost more than a week on this :)